# Querying on a pivot table using Model::query in Livewire

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-livewire

I have been using this table package lately, MedicOneSystems/livewire-datatables and I cannot seem to grab information from pivot tables.

```
    public function builder()
    {
        return $this->model::query();
    }
```

This is in their base livewire controller, then you can create your own controller by using some of the functions they offer you.
My problem is that once I enter a workbook(Workbook) I need to get the stations that are stored in a pivot table(StationWorkbook) and then go further and take the station(Station) names and everything else from the station table. I am able to get either all the stations, or just the pivot or just the workbook, but I cannot seem to be able to go through them
This is what I have tried so far in my controller.

```
    public function builder()
    {
        return $this->current_workbook->stations->query();
    }
```

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::query does not exist

```
    public function builder()
    {
        return Station::query();
    }
```

```
    public function builder()
    {
        return StationWorkbook::query();
    }
```

```
    public function builder()
    {
        return Workbook::query();
    }
```

```
    public function builder()
    {
        return Workbook::query()->where('id', $this->workbook)->stations;
    }
```

> Property [stations] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
> None of these was able to return the stations of the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the collection `stations` on the Eloquent QueryBuilder - that won't work until after you use `get()`, which you cannot do with this package, since it expects a QueryBuilder instance.

I'm not entirely sure what you need here, but if you need the station that belongs to that Workbook, then you need to return the querybuilder of the Stations model.

If we assume that you have defined a `workbook` relation on your `Station` model, then you can use `whereHas()` - which can be called on the querybuilder - to limit the data you need. I'm assuming that `$this->workbook` is the ID, and not the full instance of the model (if its the model, you need to use `$this->workbook->id`).

```php
public function builder()
{
    return Station::whereHas('workbook', function($query) {
        return $query->where('id', $this->workbook);
    });
}
```

You can also eager-load the workbook in that query by adding `with()`. Eager-loading means that Laravel will retrieve the stations joined with the workbook, so that you can access the data of both without extra queries required.

```php
public function builder()
{
    return Station::with('workbook')->whereHas('workbook', function($query) {
        return $query->where('id', $this->workbook);
    });
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I made it work with